# Here api, incorrect Speed Limit value

Tags: android, navigation, here-api

I have an `NavigationManager.PositionListener` implementation that should shows in `onPositionUpdated` speed limit value on `UI` but looks it returns incorrect value

```
Log.d("SPEEDLIMIT", "" + navigationManager.getHighSpeedWarningBoundary() + " - offset = " + navigationManager.getHighSpeedWarningOffset());
```

always returns:

```
SPEEDLIMIT: 22.222223 - offset = 2.777778
```

btw, `onSpeedExceeded` returns another values, for example: `15.555556`
but `getHighSpeedWarningBoundary` still returns `22.222223`

to check the values i converts this (m/sec->mph) and check road info in the Internet.

p.s:

i've make test in simulation mode

api v 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [RoadElement#getSpeedLimit()](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-roadelement.html#topic-apiref__getspeedlimit-void) to fetch the speed of the current road element. You can fetch the current matched RoadElement from [PositioningManager#getRoadElement()](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-positioningmanager.html#topic-apiref__getroadelement-void).

Comment: it looks ok, but still not matches with `onSpeedExceeded` of `navigationManager.addSpeedWarningListener` listener. should i prepere listener by my own that will use `RoadElement#getSpeedLimit() ` only?

Comment: Yes, please use the RoadElement one. I have to investigate internally why these may not be matching.